# How to position element's background-image relative to document / body with overflow: hidden set by parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position, background-image, overflow

## Problem

I want a `background-image` that is a `div.child` of a `div.parent` to be relatively positioned to the `body`, with `overflow: hidden` functioning for `div.parent`. Also, I want that `top: 0` of `div.child` applies to `body` not `div.parent` so that it doesn't matter where `div.parent` is positioned on the Y-axis (thus, `top:` of `div.child` doesn't need to be adjusted).

## Demonstration

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top center;
 
}

.parent {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  outline: 2px solid white; /* !!! Not visible anymore !!! */

  overflow: hidden; /* !!! Ignored by .child !!! */
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top center;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are two `background-images` that match perfectly (the same, one is inverted). Nonetheless, `overflow: hidden` applied to `div.parent` doesn't work anymore.

The `div.parent` box is indicated by a white `outline`.

## Solution needed

I need a `.parent` box that holds the same `background-image` as the `body` and no matter where this `.parent` is positioned always shows the excerpt of the underlaying `background-image` applied to the `body`. **Important**: Having `.parent` with a `background: transparent` doesn't work. This is because, I will later use the same `background-image` as applied to `body`, but one that is **edited** (like an inverted in the example fiddle).

Comment: can you share any example drawing?

Comment: Hi @visionInc did you end up finding any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the different values applied to the parent element you can easily calculate the background properties and keep the child relative to its parent:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1200px;
  margin:0;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top; 
  overflow:auto;
}

.parent {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  outline: 2px solid white; 
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* same as border */
  top:-2px;
  left: -2px;
  right:-2px;
  bottom:-2px;
  /**/
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: calc(100%/0.8) auto;  /*0.8 = 80% of the width */
  background-position: top -200px center; /* Equal to margin*/
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any solution for the case that I don't know the parent's position on the y-axis? Imagining that it is e.g. the 3rd `div.parent` with the 1st and 2nd `<div>` having different heights.

Comment: Applied to the code snippet: The unknown heights of both `<div>`s before the `div.parent` are now represented by a known `margin-top` applied to `div.parent`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `position:relative` to the parent div. Check the below fiddle. Hope it helps.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top center;
 
}

.parent {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  outline: 2px solid white; /* !!! Not visible anymore !!! */

  overflow: hidden; /* !!! Ignored by .child !!! */
  
  /*Add Relative to parent*/
  position: relative;
  
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531251445707-1f000e1e87d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=562&q=80");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top center;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But that is not exactly what I want. Both background-images don't match anymore. The `.child` needs to be positioned relative to the `body`, not the `.parent`.`